# Loss of data in simultaneous threads (JAVA)

Tags: java, performance, java-threads

I have a problem
Currently I have a function in JAVA that writes 8 simultaneous threads, it has to be that way because each writeCmd function takes around 2 minutes, (if I write 1 by 1 it would take me 16 minutes to write all of them). The problem is, when it writes it only does well with one and sometimes with anyone (there's missing information) and I don't know what is happening. When I run it individually it works without problems.

Attached image of structure and code. Any ideas?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIZSm.png)

```
Thread thread0 = new Thread(() -> {
                            try {
                                writeASICRatio(modbusClientTmp, manID, 0);
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(MainCalibration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                        });
                        
                        Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> {
                            try {
                                writeASICRatio(modbusClientTmp, manID, 1);
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(MainCalibration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                        });
                        
                        Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> {
                            try {
                                writeASICRatio(modbusClientTmp, manID, 2);
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(MainCalibration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                        });
                        
                        Thread thread3 = new Thread(() -> {
                            try {
                                writeASICRatio(modbusClientTmp, manID, 3);
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(MainCalibration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                        });
                        
                        Thread thread4 = new Thread(() -> {
                            try {
                                writeASICRatio(modbusClientTmp, manID, 4);
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(MainCalibration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                        });
                        
                        Thread thread5 = new Thread(() -> {
                            try {
                                writeASICRatio(modbusClientTmp, manID, 5);
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(MainCalibration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                        });
                        
                        Thread thread6 = new Thread(() -> {
                            try {
                                writeASICRatio(modbusClientTmp, manID, 6);
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(MainCalibration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                        });
                        
                        Thread thread7 = new Thread(() -> {
                            try {
                                writeASICRatio(modbusClientTmp, manID, 7);
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(MainCalibration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                        });

                        
                        // Start both threads
                        thread0.start();
                        thread1.start();
                        thread2.start();
                        thread3.start();
                        thread4.start();
                        thread5.start();
                        thread6.start();
                        thread7.start();
                        
                        //Note: Wait for both threads to complete
                        try
                        {
                            thread0.join();
                            thread1.join();
                            thread2.join();
                            thread3.join();
                            thread4.join();
                            thread5.join();
                            thread6.join();
                            thread7.join();
                        }
                        catch(InterruptedException ex)
                        {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

Inside the writeASICRatio function, 128 commands with different data are written to a PLC, and this PLC gives me the answer after 10 milliseconds. This is an example:

```
//Note: Start command mode
    //Note: ON - WRITE - SIZE = 3 - Value[0] = 0x72, Value[1] = 0xF5, Value[2] = 0xA2
    writeCmdASIC(sID, (short) 1, (short) 0, 3, "72", "F5", "A2", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                            mClient, 0);

    //Note: Write read start command mode.
    //Note: ON - READ - SIZE = 1 - Value = 0        
    writeCmdASIC(sID, (short)1, (short)1, 1, "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", mClient, 0);

    //Note: Read return of start command mode.
    responseData = Integer.parseInt(main.getValDataA().getValueAt(sID, 0).toString());

    if (responseData == 72)
    {
        //Note: Do nothing
    }
    else
    {
        message += "M" + manID + "S" + sID + ".Start command mode not received correctly. Aborting calibration mode... <br>";
        return "";
    }
```

Here I write a command with those parameters (72, F5, A2), then I write a read command, and the read is automatically reflected in a table, I take the value from the table that matches 72 in that case and that's it. That command is for verification, the other 128 are write only.

Comment: What exactly are you writing to? Keep in mind that race conditions and other issues can arise if you're sharing memory between threads without taking the proper precautions.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Probably no one knows what writeASICRatio() is and if it is safe-thread, even if the symptoms indicate it isn't.

Comment: First, does it work when you only use one thread?  Second, why are you using multiple threads?  Third, how do you know `writeCmdASIC()` is thread-safe?  Fourth, what does `writeCmdASIC()` do?  You still haven't provided a complete example.

Comment: OK @AndrewHenle
1. It works without threads if I put the 8 functions one after another.
2. I am using multiple threads because I need to shorten the writing time of 8 sensors, as I explained above, it takes me 2 minutes to execute each writeAsicRatio() function, each function equals one sensor, in this case it would take me 16 minutes for the 8 sensors, there is no problem here, the problem is that the structure can be reproduced up to 192 sensors and if it takes me 2 minutes for each one, it would take a total of approximately 6 hours to execute all of them.

Comment: 3. Information is being lost when I run all the threads, that's why I made this post, to know how to fix it.
4. WriteCMDAsic() is a function that writes a command to a PLC, the PLC answers in 10 milliseconds and I get an answer.

Comment: @R.Lerma And you have yet to answer how you know *all* of the calls you make to write to the PLC are thread-safe and how you know multiple threads writing to the PLC at the same time can work without corrupting data.

Comment: I call the command to the plc through the jamod-1.2 library, I don't know if it's safe for threads, your second question, I don't know if it can work without damaging the data, with the answers I'm getting it's obvious that information is lost , but I don't know what extra functionality to use so that this doesn't happen.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.